# Remove goto in C

Tags: c

I want to remove `goto` statements in my C code. The following shows  my C code.

```
void placeFruit(void)
{ 
 resetfruitX:fruitX=rand()%20;
 if(fruitX==0||fruitX==width)
 goto resetfruitX;

 resetfruitY:fruitY=rand()%20;
 if(fruitY==0||fruitY==height)
 goto resetfruitY;
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What do you know about loops? More specifically `do ... while(...)` loops? What do your text-books say?

Comment: Try the following thinking technique: there is something you want to program. Then you invent a way of programming it (using `goto` statements). Now do the whole exercise again: what do you want to program?  You will soon realise you'll automatically end up with a while- or a repeat-loop, which is exactly what you need. (`goto` statements are in fact a bad way to replace loops)

Comment: There's no reason to use `goto`/loops here to begin with. It can be rewritten as something like `fruitX = rand()%19 + 1; fruitX += (fruitX >= width)`. Or, if `width==19`, just `fruitX = rand()%18 + 1`.

Comment: Why loop at all?  Why not use `rand() % (width - 2) + 1`?  That generates a value between 1 and (width - 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void placeFruit(void){    
  do fruitX=rand()%20; while(fruitX==0||fruitX==width);
  do fruitY=rand()%20; while(fruitY==0||fruitY==width);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: And some good formatting is always appreciated. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use loops and perhaps improve readability a bit with an internal helper function:

```
static inline int place (int max)
{
  int fruit=0;

  while(fruit==0 || fruit==max)
    fruit = rand() % 20;

  return fruit;
}

void placeFruit(void)
{ 
  fruitX = place(width);
  fruitY = place(height);
}
```

`do-while` is a micro-optimization over `while` but works too - it doesn't matter much which one you pick. The performance bottleneck here is the `rand()` call. In theory this loop could go on for ever, so maybe consider a better strategy like having two containers/matrices, one with "used" coordinates and one with "free" coordinates.